# How can i change the database in auth.php?

Tags: php, laravel

how can i change the database in laravel auth.php (config/auth.php)? I am using multiple databases and want the users to be stored in another.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first you should define connections in config/database.php:

```
'connections' => [
    'global' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('first_db_name', '127.0.0.1'),
            ...
            ],
    'tennant' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'host' => env('sec_db_name', '127.0.0.1'),
            ],
    ]
```

then add them in `auth.php`:

```
'guards' => [
    [...]
    'global' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'globals',
    ],
    'tennant' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'tennants',
    ],
],

[...]
'providers' => [
    [...]
    'globals' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\UserGlobal::class,
    ],
    'tennants' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\UserTennant::class,
    ],
],
```

define protected `$connection = 'connection name'` in each authenticable model
and finally using in model:

```
protected $connection = 'connectionname';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Lol turns out I was using the wrong model in the controller :/ 1 hours of my time can not be returned :D

Answer (score 0):

Set the [Connection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#database-connections) in model User.php or the model related to Auth.